# R package : should i load my package in Roxygen comments?

Tags: r, package, roxygen2

In my Roxygen `@examples` tag, i'm used to load the package that i'm documenting :

```
#' @examples 
#' load(my_pakage)
#' my_awesome_output = function_from_my_package(exemple_data)
```

then, checking the package gives output like :

```
-  installing the package to process help pages
   Loading required namespace: my_package
```

What type of exemples should i use :

- The form I actualy use
- A form without the `library(my_package)` without `my_package::` prefix
- A form without the `library(my_package)` but with `my_package::` prefix to calls ?

Comment: I tend to not include the `library(my_pkg)` in examples, since the package should be loaded when someone accesses its doc. I don't put the `::` either on my packages' functions, but include it for any function from another package (and those *should* be included at the top of your example)

Comment: Thanks @RoB for the details.